# Operator= overload failure with use of copy constructor of other class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I am trying to fix a problem related to overloading assigment operator to be able to assign one list to another.

I have two classes:

```
class CarList{

    private:
    Car* head;
    void clear();

    public:
    CarList();
    ~CarList();
    CarList(const CarList & olist);
    CarList & operator= (const CarList & olist);

    void add_car(char* name, int number, int id);
    void remove_make(char* name);

};
```

and

```
class Car{

    private:
    char* make;
    int license_number;
    int owner_ID;
    Car* next;


    public:
    //constructor with data presentation
    Car(char* name, int number, int id);
    Car(const Car &car);
    //destructor with data presentation - for further use
    ~Car();
    //Rest of methods
    Car*& GetNext();
    char* GetMake();
    int GetLic();
    int GetID();
    int SetID(int id);
    void Print();
    };
```

I wrote following method to overload an operator:

```
CarList& CarList::operator= (const CarList & olist)
{
    clear();


    if (this == &olist) return *this; // detecting if target is same as source

    if(this->head != NULL) this->head=new Car(*olist.head);
    return *this;
}
```

which calls Car copy constructor:

```
Car::Car(const Car &car)
{
    this->make = new char[strlen(car.make)+1];
    strcpy(this->make, car.make);
    this->license_number = car.license_number;
    this->owner_ID = car.owner_ID;
    if (car.next != NULL)
        this->next = new Car(*car.next);
    else
        this->next = NULL;

}
```

but program crashes and I don't really know why. Copy constructor in Carlist works totally okay using Car copy constructor call.

Comment: Your impl. of `Car::Car(const Car &car)` looks weird. You are copying some things twice (and hence produce memleaks). Why?

Comment: @cwschmidt I am sorry, I made a mistake while pasting. Fixed.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger, to track down where it crashes?

Comment: Unfortunately, debugger refuses to work, it stops after Print... which just prints elements of Car object... (standard cout command). Hovewer, printing works okay.

Comment: The code you have posted so far looks viable (although not great style). You must be making a mistake in some of the code you didn't post. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `CarList::operator=` either does nothing or leaks memory , although that in itself wouldn't cause a crash

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PTpM1x26

here I posted it

Comment: The "M" means "Minimal" I'm sure you can remove 3/4 of that code and still find the problem happening. It should be small enough to fit into the SO question, not external link

Comment: I stripped my code and found a bug causing it. Thanks!